# Converting pathname from relative to absolute in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I am trying to get ClearCase to give me an absolute pathname. (The tree from the view root to the current element would be fine too).

`cleartool desc -fmt "%Xn"` yields the checked out pathname - excellent. But I need the `\vob\directory\to\the\file` as well.

Is there a simple way to do this? I know one way is to convert to the OID and then back, but that is very slow - I'd like to at least keep an eye towards speed.

Answer (score 0):

Since, according to [fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), '`%Xn`' is about the [extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904), you need to compute the path of the file within the view.

If you know the full path of the file, you need to compute the view root only one (/path/to/view) in order to substract it from the full path of the file (/path/to/view/vob/path/to/file), as suggested in [ClearCase - file system path to element path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651808/clearcase-file-system-path-to-element-path).